# How to redirect to external url if method return ResponseEntity<Object>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have method in controller that return ResponseEntity Object

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> processInsert(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return insertService.handleInsert(request);
}

public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInsert(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

    User user = createUser(params, request);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now when this execute it return me JSON in browser, how can i make it redirect me to some URL, for example www.google.com if i need to keep this method returning ResponseEntity Object

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) from spring.

Comment: @CodeMatrix I saw this documentation, but i can't find example that i need

Comment: change return `type` to `String` and return `"redirect:http://www.google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understood your question  completely, if you want a ResponseEntity to be returned and then redirect to another page, this info will be lost after redirecting.
If you want your endpoint to be redirected to another page, you need to return a String type from your controller method, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = { "/testRedirect" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
public String testRedirect() {
    return "redirect:http://www.google.com";
}
```

If you want to display an error or something in case your program misbehaves due to incorrect input data or anything, you can just do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = { "/testRedirect" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
public String testRedirect(HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
    // if error occurs
    servletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        "explained error");
    return null; // return null to indicate your program that the request has finished with the error.
    // if all works correctly return the redirect String.
    return "redirect:http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: Hi, i've edited my question and add code for this method handleInsert. The problem is that i need first check in user which type it is and then redirect to correct url. For example if he is admin redirect to google.com, in other case redirect to youtube.com. do you know what would be the best way to make this